# Android with Laravel 5.5

Tags: android, laravel, sentinel, cartalyst-sentinel

I'm working on an Android project, and I make Laravel login system using Sentinel. I am wanting to connect Laravel with Android - it always shows me the error

> token mismatch.

I don't want to except my route.

Comment: what do you mean by token mismatch error, post your code here so that we can have a look

Comment: 1) Post some code that you are having trouble with 2) Explain what you have tried 3) Clearly state your problem

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you understand it's a CSRF token issue, have you verified that it is being sent in your request headers?

You should see `X-CSRF-TOKEN: your token...`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to disable CSRF tokens, then you will need to retrieve the CSRF in one request, then pass the retrieved token along with your POST request.

Please refer to this answer

[access laravel app from android app with csrf token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627477/access-laravel-app-from-android-app-with-csrf-token?answertab=active#tab-top)